# Creating new column using output of if else statement causes error

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas, dataframe

I am using the following code,

```
if(df.month == 3 or df.month == 4 or df.month == 5):
    df.test = 'A'
elif(df.month == 6 or df.month == 7 or df.month == 8):
    df.test = 'B'
else:
    df.test = 'C'
```

But while using this, I am getting the following error,

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**Update**:

```
print df.columns

Unnamed: 0      int64
year            int64
month           int64
day             int64
dep_time      float64
dep_delay     float64
arr_time      float64
arr_delay     float64
carrier        object
tailnum        object
flight          int64
origin         object
dest           object
air_time      float64
distance        int64
hour          float64
minute        float64


print df.dtypes

dtype: object
```

Can anybody help me in finding the error here?

Comment: How can we know what `df` is?

Comment: Please post more of your code.  Are you working with pandas here?  If so, tag the question as such.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @MarcinZdunek I just updated little more of df. Can you please check it?

Comment: @Matthew I want to create a new column, based on the value of month column. "test" is a new column which I am trying to create based on the month value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best is use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), because you can't compare a scalar with an array like that using `if` or `elif` it becomes ambiguous:

```
print df

   year  month  day
0  2005      3   20
1  2005      4   20
2  2005      5   20
3  2005      6   20
4  2005      7   20
5  2005      8   20
6  2005      9   20

df['test'] = 'C'
df.loc[df['month'].isin([3,4,5]) , 'test'] = 'A'
df.loc[df['month'].isin([6,7,8]) , 'test'] = 'B'

print df  

   year  month  day test
0  2005      3   20    A
1  2005      4   20    A
2  2005      5   20    A
3  2005      6   20    B
4  2005      7   20    B
5  2005      8   20    B
6  2005      9   20    C
```

Or you can fill column `test` by value `C` this way:

```
df.loc[df['month'].isin([3,4,5]) , 'test'] = 'A'
df.loc[df['month'].isin([6,7,8]) , 'test'] = 'B'
df.loc[df['month'].isin([1,2,9,10,11,12]) , 'test'] = 'C'

print df    

   year  month  day test
0  2005      3   20    A
1  2005      4   20    A
2  2005      5   20    A
3  2005      6   20    B
4  2005      7   20    B
5  2005      8   20    B
6  2005      9   20    C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprehension to create your `test` column:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'month' : pd.Series(range(1,13))})
>>> df['test'] = ['A' if m in [3,4,5] else 
...               'B' if m in [6,7,8] else 
...               'C' for m in df['month']]
>>> df
    month test
0       1    C
1       2    C
2       3    A
3       4    A
4       5    A
5       6    B
6       7    B
7       8    B
8       9    C
9      10    C
10     11    C
11     12    C
```

Or you can apply a function, which produces the same result:

```
>>> def value(month):
...     if month in [3,4,5]:
...         return 'A'
...     if month in [6,7,8]:
...         return 'B'
...     return 'C'
>>> df['test'] = df['month'].apply(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def valuesetter(x):
    if x in [3,4,5]: return "A"
    elif x in [6,7,8]: return "B"
    else: return "C"

df["test"] = list(map(valuesetter,df.month))
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception message you're getting is pretty self explanatory.  df['month'] is a series, and the truth value of a series is ambiguous because it represents a series of truth values.  You can do what you're trying to do with `pd.Series.map`

```
def assignmentFunction(value):
    if value in [3, 4, 5]:
        return 'A'
    elif value in [6, 7, 8]:
        return 'B'
    else:
        return 'C'

df['test'] = df['month'].map(assignmentFunction)
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer mainly tries to explain the error that you're seeing.  As I'm not a `pandas` user, I'll let the other answers speak to better ways to write this code...

---

`df.month` returns an array.  `some_array == 6` will return another array (constructed such that `new_array[i] == True` iff `some_array[i] == 6`).

Because of situations like this, in numpy, an array does not have a truth value (unlike normal python sequences).  So, to test if an array is truthy, you need to specify what you mean.  e.g. to specify that *all* elements must be truthy, you'd want:  `(df.month == 6).all()`

Comment: while using all command, the error gets solved. But the if condition doesn't work. So this solution didn't work for this particular problem