# How to create a new column based on x and y rows

Tags: python, csv, numpy-ndarray

I currently have a CSV full of information. I am able to import my CSV into numpy (currently using Anaconda/Jupyter, let me know if there is something better I should be using. :)). I am trying to create a new column based on information from 2 other columns in the dataframe. For example, I want to have a code (e.g., A, B, C) for each person based on 2 factors. My first thought is to use if statements, but it doesn't look like I can do that for Dataframes.

Any help or resources on how to get started would be fantastic. I don't have any code at the moment, and am trying to find the best place to start.

This is what I was wanting to try out, but it doesn't look like this would work with that I'm trying to do. Is this still the best place the start? [Creating new column using output of if else statement causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759318/creating-new-column-using-output-of-if-else-statement-causes-error)

This is not my code, but the best I could find to start with.

```
df.loc[df['month'].isin([3,4,5]), 'test'] = 'A'
df.loc[df['month'].isin([6,7,8]), 'test'] = 'B'
df.loc[df['month'].isin([1,2,9,10,11,12]) , 'test'] = 'C'
```

Would it be possible to move 'column_1' into 'month', and include 'AND' 'column_2', then 'test' = 'A'?

I want to create a new column as A, B, C, etc. based on column_1 and column_2

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take a look at [How to create good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [mcve] for your question, with sample input and output, so that we can better help you

Comment: Ok, I think I've been asking the question in the wrong way. This looks like what I'm trying to accomplish. I will report back after I've worked through this using what I've found.

Comment: it seems as though your solution will be a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34759662/117346410) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757551/pandas-indexing-using-multiple-isin-clauses)